# GetFeatureInfo request to Geoserver returns an error,

Tags: proxy, openstreetmap, geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I am trying to make a GetFeatureInfo request with WMS on Open Layers to Geoserver. The request appears to be made and loads on every click as expected but the "image" crashes every time. The request is made through a Proxy on my own computer which appears to be working well. Here is an image of the events and the code I have been using. As i am quite inexperienced with all components of this any help would be appreciated. Thank you guys.

[image: What i get returned in Open Layers]

The script :

```
  <script>


    var layers = [];
    layers[0] = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/AL2/wms?',
            params: { LAYERS: 'AL2:A2', 'TILED': true, projection: 'EPSG:4326', VERSION: '1.1.1' },
            servertype: 'geoserver'

        })
    });

    layers[1] = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    layers[2] = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: layers,
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([13, 56]),
            zoom: 8,
            EPSG: 4326,
        })
    });


    function switchLayer(evt) {
        layers[evt.value].setVisible(evt.checked);
    }

    map.on('singleclick', function (event) {
        var url = '../../proxy/proxy.aspx?url=' + layers[0].getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl
            (event.coordinate,
                map.getView().getResolution(), map.getView().getProjection().getCode(),
                {
                    INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',
                    Layers: "AL2:A2"
                });
        if (url) {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
                '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>'
        }
    });


</script>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
```

```
    <meta charset = "utf-8"/>

     <title > OpenLayers </title>

     <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://openlayers.org/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type = "text/css">

<script src = "https://openlayers.org/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js" script type = "text/javascript" ></script>
         </head>
         <body>
```

Geoserver

LTU

GPS

Comment: Please add the actual request that is sent and the response that you receive - both can be found in the debugger (press F12) of your browser. You may also find useful information in the GeoServer log file.

Comment: @IanTurton 
Sorry for the late response Ian, heres what I could pull out from the debugger that felt relevant. Hope it tells you more than it tells me. https://imgur.com/a/hoQABTg

Comment: please [edit] your question with the text not an image. But from a quick glance it looks like a CORS issue